# MongoDB secondary crashes on initial sync. admin.system.profile

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

Im setting up a replica set on my machine for testing but I can't get past syncing the nodes. When I start my secondary up it seems to be going OK until I get a log in the secondary along the lines of

```
...
oplog sync 3 of 3
Create profile collection admin.system.profile
..\src\mongo\util\stacktrace.windows.cpp(174)
...
```

After that the secondary running as a service dies on windows and each time I try to restart it it does the same thing. These are the same version of mongo 3.2.3. My profiling level is set to 2 on the primary which I know is high because that essentially logs every single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the system.profile collection had some bad documents in it. Some had no _id field. Maybe left over from an upgrade or something. I don't know. Anyway deleted the system.profile collection and brought the replica sets back up and turned on profiling back on and everything seems ok.